# порядковый номер элемента последовательности

Tags: python, числовые-последовательности

Дана последовательность из n целых чисел. Найти номер минимального элемента в этой последовательности.

С клавиатуры вводится целое число n.

Затем вводятся элементы последовательности - целые числа (каждое в отдельной строке).

Выводимым результатом работы программы является число (номер минимального элемента последовательности, нумерация начинается с единицы).

Если последовательность содержит несколько одинаковых минимальных элементов, результатом является номер первого из них.

Задачу необходимо решить в 2 этапа:

Сначала ввести входные данные и сохранить их в коллекцию заданного типа (список).
С помощью оператора цикла for обойти все элементы коллекции и выполнить их обработку в соответствии с заданием.

то есть, такой вариант не подойдет:

```
lst = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))]
print(max(lst))
print(min(lst))
```

Либо вычислить индексы мин и макс так:

```
for index,element in enumerate(list1):
 if element == min(list1):
 print(index)
 

for index,value in enumerate(list1):
 if value == max(list1):
 print(index)
```

Такой вариант тоже отклоняется, потому как нельзя использовать стандартную функцию минимума, генерацию списка и выражения-генераторы:

```
lst = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))]
min_index = [index for index, element in enumerate(lst) if element == min(lst)][0]
 
print(min_index)
```

еще вариант, все хорошо но проваливается тест при n=0, где само число - ноль:

```
a = []
b = int(input())
for i in range(1,b):
    a.append(i)
print(f'{a[0]}')
```

Comment: В заголовке должна быть суть вопроса. в теле вопроса - ваш код. пока вопрос успешно движется к закрытию.

Comment: добавил деталей

Comment: приведенный вариант не подойдет, потому что вы не пытаетесь ответить на вопрос задания. а там даже расписано, как нужно это сделать. исходный список вы получили. где ваш обход этого списка циклом for с поиском индексов максимального и минимального элементов?

Comment: еще обновил, просьба помочь)

Comment: там суть в том, что не дает использовать стандартную функцию минимума

Comment: Если нельзя использовать стандартную функцию минимума, сделайте свою с тем же именем и оставьте остальной код как есть. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# ввести количество чисел
n = int(input())

# ввести сами числа
a = []
for _ in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))

# отыскать индекс минимального числа
j = 0
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] < a[j]:
        j = i

# напечатать исправленный индекс минимального числа
print(j + 1)
```

Comment: абсолютно верно! Благодарю всех, столько мучился

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам нужно что-то совсем простое типа этого:

```py
a = []

for i in range(1,b): # задаётся тестами(судя по заданию)
    a.append(i)

print(f'{a[0]}- минимальное значение, {a[-1]}- максимальное значение.')
```

Если я правильно понял задачу и вам нельзя пользоваться встроенными фишками данного ЯП.
Надеюсь , вам это помогло.

Comment: *«Дана последовательность из n целых чисел.»* Значит, **не вы** ее строите.

Comment: `a = []
b = int(input())
for i in range(1,b):
    a.append(i)
print(f'{a[0]}')`

Comment: так вроде бы верно, но тест при n=1, где само число - ноль, проваливается. Единственная эта проблема пока осталась

Comment: А если  в строке `for i in range(-5,20,1):` вы напишете?

Comment: находит минимальное верно, -5

Comment: у вас все верно, кроме того что при n=1 и числе ноль тест проваливается

Comment: он просто не указывает порядковый номер

Comment: А максимальноe ?
Похоже у вас проблема в формировании `range()`.
range("начало","конечное число +1(потому что обрывает счёт на нём)", "шаг" )
Вы так вводите range() ?
Это не с codewars ли какого-то задание, если да , то пришлите ссылку пожалуйста?

Comment: вставил код в конец самого описания. Максимальное не требуется по условию

Comment: Test input:
1
0
Correct output:
1

Your code output: "здесь пусто, ничего не выводит"

Comment: Добавьте проверку `if  0>= b <= 1: print(f'{a[0]}- минимальное значение')', должно отработать верно.
Либо просто меняйте range() правильно.

Comment: ничего не изменилось. Range(1,b) - здесь внутри скобок что-то стоит заменить?

Comment: Да.
Напишите `range(b)`.

Comment: Но в этом случае нумерация начинается с нуля, ошибка сразу

Comment: я попробовал b заменить на 100000. Тест с нулем прокатывает, а какой-то неизвестный тест заваливается в итоге

Comment: ```python
a = []

for i in range(1,b): # задаётся тестами(судя по заданию)
    if b == 0:
        print(f'{a}- минимальное значение.')
    else:
        a.append(i)


print(f'{a[0]}- минимальное значение, {a[-1]}- максимальное значение.')```

Comment: он трижды выдает единицу. А без ввода b работать не желает вообще

Comment: вариант до этого был максимально близко к истине

Comment: Где в решении было "Затем вводятся элементы последовательности - целые числа (каждое в отдельной строке)" ?